# How to check if a string contains punctuation c++

Tags: c++, loops, iterator, punctuation

I am attempting to iterate over a string to check for punctuation. I've tried to use ispunct() but am receiving an error that there is no matching fucntion for call to ispunct. Is there a better way to implement this?

```
for(std::string::iterator it = oneWord.begin(); it != oneWord.end(); it++)
{
    if(ispunct(it))
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using a range based for loop: `for (auto const& ch: str) { if ispunct(ch) {} }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`it` is an iterator; it points to a character in a string. You have to dereference it to get the thing it points to.

```
if(ispunct(static_cast<unsigned char>(*it)))
```

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a better way to implement this?

Use [std::any_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::string s = "Contains punctuation!!";
   std::string s2 = "No puncuation";
   std::cout << std::any_of(s.begin(), s.end(), ::ispunct) << '\n';
   std::cout << std::any_of(s2.begin(), s2.end(), ::ispunct) << '\n';
}
```

[Live Example](https://www.ideone.com/oyRhev)